# Automation: How to get downloaded path of a file that was downloaded from the Web browser

Tags: javascript, powershell, google-chrome, cmd, automation

I am writing a automation script to download a excel file from a link that was opened using Chrome Browser. Is there a option to get full path of the downloaded Location? This script is going to be run across different machines. So i do not want to specify the default download location in my system and find the file in that path.

I have also tried using Windows CMD where i input the file name in CMD, searches the entire system and pulls the path. But it is taking around 2 to 3 minutes to do this search. Is there any better efficient method like using a JavaScript to get the downloaded location quicker?

Below is the windows command i tried (taking 2 to 3 minutes)..

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir "<FILENAME>" /b/a-d/od/t:c/s') 
DO echo %i > %tmp%\lastfile.txt
```

Comment: There will be different file path syntax for Windows and POSIX based machines such as Mac, Unix.

My suggestions will be to get the system access and create all together new folder in default workspace in those machines and then store the excel files there. Now, since you know the folder name, you can access them easily.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same in JScript. It writes a web file to stdout.

```
Sub HttpGet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set File = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    File.Open "GET", Arg(1), False
    File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
    File.Send
    txt=File.ResponseText
    'Putting in line endings
    Outp.write txt
    If err.number <> 0 then 
        Outp.writeline "" 
        Outp.writeline "Error getting file" 
        Outp.writeline "==================" 
        Outp.writeline "" 
        Outp.writeline "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
        Outp.writeline "Source " & err.source 
        Outp.writeline "" 
        Outp.writeline "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
        Outp.writeline  File.getAllResponseHeaders
        Outp.writeline LCase(Arg(1))
    End If
End Sub
```